# Filter a collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to filter a collection in order to return only items with fullname that is like the one given in parmaters

```
   public function searchFriend($fullName){
        return Auth::user()->friends->filter(function ($item) use ($fullName) {
             return false !== stristr($item->friend->full_name, $fullName);
        });
    }
```

the function actually is not returning the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing the collection directly, you can do the filtering in SQL.

```php
public function searchFriend($fullName){
    return Auth::user()
        ->friends()
        ->where('full_name', 'like', '%'.$fullName.'%')
        ->get();
}
```

If you, for whichever reason, need to do it on the collection, then the problem with your current code is that `$item` represents the friend, so you're checking `$item->friend->full_name` instead of `$item->full_name`.

```php
public function searchFriend($fullName){
    return Auth::user()
        ->friends
        ->filter(function ($item) use ($fullName) {
             return false !== stristr($item->full_name, $fullName);
        });
}
```

Comment: the reason why i need to do it in a collection is because i don't have a column in my users table called fullname bu it's a function in my User model

Answer (score 1):

I guess `friend` is a relationship to the **User** model so it could be

```
public function searchFriend($fullName) 
{
    return Auth::user()->friends()->whereHas('friend', function ($query) use ($fullName) {
        $query->where('full_name', 'like', "%{$fullName}%");
    })->get();
}
```

If you have **first_name** and **last_name** in User model then you can use `concat`.

```
public function searchFriend($fullName)
{
    return Auth::user()->friends()->whereHas('friend', function ($query) use ($fullName) {
        $query->whereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like ?", ["%{$fullName}%"]);
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: the reason why i need to do it in a collection is because i don't have a column in my users table called fullname bu it's a function in my User model

Comment: I edited my post, you can join two string with concat in mysql.

Comment: it's actually returning wrong results , what's the purpose of whereHas('friend') ? the relation friends returns all the current user's friends

Comment: You had **friend** relationship in OP.

Comment: in my post $item->friend->full_name already returns the fullname of the friend i need just to filter no more